# Eclipse Milo: How to read history data?

Tags: java, opc-ua, milo

I've tried write data to Eclipse Milo server and read history data the following way:

```java
HistoryReadDetails hrd = new ReadRawModifiedDetails(false, DateTime.MIN_VALUE, DateTime.MIN_VALUE,UInteger.MAX,false);
TimestampsToReturn ttr = TimestampsToReturn.Both;
List<HistoryReadValueId> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new HistoryReadValueId(new NodeId(2,"HelloWorld/ScalarTypes/Int32"), null, QualifiedName.NULL_VALUE,null));
HistoryReadResponse hrr = client.historyRead(hrd, ttr, true, list).get();
```

But got the following:

```
HistoryReadResult{StatusCode=StatusCode{name=Bad_NotSupported, value=0x803D0000, quality=bad}, ContinuationPoint=ByteString{bytes=null}, HistoryData=ExtensionObject{encoded=null, encodingTypeId=NodeId{ns=0, id=0}}}
```

Is this feature supported by Milo (I use local Milo as local server too) or I do something wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

The Milo Server SDK has support for implementing History services, but does not implement them for you.

You'll need to find a server that supports and implements history to develop and test your client against.

Comment: Thank you! I've donwnloaded Unified Automation CPP Server, can connect to it, try to get history information similar way and got the following error:

HistoryReadResult{StatusCode=StatusCode{name=Bad_ContinuationPointInvalid, value=0x804A0000, quality=bad}, ContinuationPoint=ByteString{bytes=null}, HistoryData=ExtensionObject{encoded=null, encodingTypeId=NodeId{ns=0, id=0}}}

Tried to use ByteString.NULL_VALUE instead of null, result the same. What's wrong with it and how ContinuationPoint can be wrong for first request ?